# How to add a child to children of a scrollable widget in flutter without rendering old child?

Tags: flutter, performance, render

I want after user reach end of page view, a page add to the end and remove from start .
The old pages should not render again. ( Because my page widget is complex and need too much resource to render)
So I create list of widget and add (or remove) a widget in onPageChange .That list is set as children of a page view . But It's not working because I jump to a page in onPageChange !
Because I don't want the user reach end of Page view .
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: share your code

Comment: The code is too simple but not working . 
@brook-yonas